# Nativescript - how to use :highlighted pseudo selector

Tags: nativescript, radlistview

In my buttons and listview items are not highlighted when they're tapped on.

How can I get that to work?

Using Telerik RadListview.

Comment: The pseudoselector works as expected - just like any other pseudoselector. Could you show us what you tried?

Comment: I tried a few things - it seems like highlighted PS works only on Button element. I changed a working Button element to Label and it didn't work. For the RadListview item I created an item-active:highlighted {} css class and added that to the item class list. No workee!

Comment: `:highlighted{background-color: red;}`

Comment: That is correct - `:highlighted` currently only works with buttons.